# Create an additional field with "Rechnung an" via "Verschicken an" in Magento 2 Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

If a different delivery address is indicated, i want create an additional field with "Rechnung an" via "Verschicken an" and display the entered address here. Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to add a new field to the address model. All you need to do is to follow the steps present on this page of the official Magento 2 documentation:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html